# Looking for HeatonResearchNeural library

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network

i'm working on a machine learning project using neural networks, i found i piece of C# code but it needs the following namespace which i searched a while for it.

```
using HeatonResearchNeural.Util;
```

any clue ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of FCL (Framework Class Library) and please look for the source code it self or look for downloadable code which might be consumed by the referenced C# code.

**Updated**: It seems you are referring source library which is part of a book or it's exercise chapters.
[Find full source code here](https://code.google.com/p/jeffheaton-bookcode/source/browse/trunk/HeatonResearchNeural/?r=12#HeatonResearchNeural/Util)

Comment: Agreed (and I am the one who wrote the book).  You can also find it here:  http://www.heatonresearch.com/download